# Is it safe to delete the default "postgres" role?

Tags: postgresql, role

I'm trying to understand if it's okay for me drop the "postgres" role, or at the least, remove it as the superuser.
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm trying to understand if it's okay for me drop the "postgres" role,
>   or at the least, remove it as the superuser.

Dropping the role owning the template databases and all the system tables of all databases is not possible. There is even a specific error for that, should you try to `DROP ROLE postgres`:

**ERROR:  cannot drop role postgres because it is required by the database system**

---

It's technically possible to remove the `superuser` capability to postgres, but  if there is no superuser left in the system, any administrative task that only a superuser can do will be out of reach, and that would be really inconvenient.

On the other hand, it's entirely reasonable to deny through `pg_hba.conf` the ability for the `postgres` role to connect remotely, and also to set and enforce a password for the `postgres` account even for local-only connections.